# how to configure the default kibana index pattern after installation

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have installed ELK stack for elastic search with kibana to start using logstash but I get the following issue with the no default index set?

[kilbana no default index set screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvA2y.png)

The page asks me a question "Do you have indices matching the pattern?" but I don't see a way to answer it and move forward!  It's my first time installing this.  Any ideas?

I've successfully got the services installed and running using this tutorial [install ELK Stack](https://logz.io/blog/installing-the-elk-stack-on-windows/)

**Update #1**

Have entered http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices into my browser and it displays the following

```
yellow open .kibana qypsy4K-Qt-jm4_wll9PCQ 1 1 1 0 3.6kb 3.6kb
```

**Update 2**

After downloading curl and attempting to import data I received the following curl messages.

[data import using curl messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEVSc.png)

**Update #3**

I've downloaded data from [www.kaggle.com](https://www.kaggle.com/) and executed the command following command to import the data but the command prompt just sits there, I've included a screen shot below of the console window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter your index name in the input box in the place of logstash-*. You will see your index name by going to localhost:9200/_cat/indices.

Once you put your index name it will automatically gather the fields from your index and prompt you for a time field which you can set or ignore.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, I've updated the question with the results after using your advice, I'm not sure what part of the result to use as the default index?  If I paste the entire result kibana says "invalid index name pattern".

Comment: Looks like you have not pushed any data into your Elasticsearch server. Here's where you can get some sample data, if you need. http://ikeptwalking.com/elasticsearch-sample-data/ . If you follow that example, your index name will be companydatabase which you can put in that textbox in Kibana.

Comment: Great, just trying it now.  Thanks,

Comment: I've updated my question, when running the curl commands to import data I received messages that look like there's a problem (see update #2 for the command prompt messages).  Is this okay?  Thanks,

Comment: Is your Elasticsearch running? To check go to your browser and type localhost:9200. You should get back some info about your cluster. You probably have seen this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/running-elasticsearch.html